# Implement Candidate key during table creation in mysql

Tags: mysql, key

I am creating a table Books (accno, ISBN, title, authors, publisher, purchaseprice, purchasedate), and i want to set ISBN as a candidate key during the creation. How do i set/implement Candidate Key on ISBN column ?

Comment: Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html you can also create index as part of create table - OR is your question which column(s) would make the perfect candidate key?

Comment: @P.Salmon I would like to know how to implement the candidate key feature on ISBN column

Comment: Then read the links and come back if you have a problem.